# How to show div with same data attribute like selection

Tags: jquery

If got an selection with with and value, which is the same value as an class data attribute.
I want to onchange show the current div with the same value as the option value.
My code is this:

```js
$('.test_c').hide();
$('#test').on("change", function() {
  let me = $(this).val();
  $('test_c' + me.data('document-id')).show();
})
```

```html
<select name="test" id="test" class="test">
  <option value="default">Select</option>
  <option value="1">Test</option>
</select>
<div class="test_C" data-document-id="1" style="display: none">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're quite close.   Couple of points:

- `me` is a string:

```
let me = $(this).val()`
```

will set `me` to the value, not an element/node/jquery, this value will be a *string*, so you can only use string methods.   `me` would normally be just `$(this)` and a better variable name might fit here, eg `var documentId=...`

- Use attribute selectors `[attribute-name]` to match an attribute.
- Use `.class` for class selector (missing the `.` on `$('test_c' +`)
- Class selectors are case-sensitive, so `$(".test_c")` will not find `<div class="test_C"` - can be easier just to always use lowercase.

Giving:

```js
$('#test').on("change", function() {
  let docId = $(this).val();
  $('.test_c').hide();
  $(`.test_c[data-document-id=${docId}]`).show();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="test" id="test" class="test">
  <option value="default">Select</option>
  <option value="1">Test</option>
</select>
<div class="test_c" data-document-id="default"><em>please select above</em></div>
<div class="test_c" data-document-id="1" style="display: none">ONE</div>
```